# Core Data: fetch result from two entities, and the result contain info in two entities

Tags: ios, core-data

There are two entities:

[image]

I want to make a course table.

The first entity is `Course`, the second is `TimeAndPlace`. At university, there are some courses and one course maybe has different time or place. Now I want to fetch `Course`s and their associated `TimeAndPlace`s in every weekday. But there some limits: if current week is between start week and last week whose period in term, the course is needed; in this courses, select the course whose weekday equal to a certain weekday. Finally, I want to get the course and their associated time and place.

I'm not too familiar with Core Data, Can you help me?

**Edited**:
Just like SQL:

```
SELECT Course.courseName, TimeAndPlace.courseLocation, TimeAndPlace.courseOrder
FROM Course, TimeAndPlace
WHERE Course.startWeekTheCourseInTheTerm <= currentWeek AND Course.lastWeekTheCourseInTheTerm >= currentWeek AND timeAndPlaces.weekday == currentweekday;
```

**effect drawing:**

[image]

Comment: don't you miss an attibute "timeFrom" and "timeUntil" for setting the y and height of your cells? just by the way

Comment: Just use courseOrder instead of timeFrom and timeUntil. For exmaple, 1-2, the value of courseOrder is "0102", 11-12 is "1112".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this? with an 1:n relation it's not that complicated, will get more fun with n:m :P

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Course" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

NSPredicate* = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startWeekTheCourseInTheTerm <= %d AND lastWeekTheCourseInTheTerm >= %d AND timeAndPlaces.weekday == %d", currentWeek, currentWeek, weekday];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

or if you need complete week (for example to show in a tableView)

```
NSPredicate* = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startWeekTheCourseInTheTerm <= %d AND lastWeekTheCourseInTheTerm >= %d", currentWeek, currentWeek];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeAndPlaces.weekday" ascending:YES]]];
```

sort by weekday and courseOrder:
(so you have

-> Monday
--> 1
--> 2
--> 3
-> Tuesday
--> 1
...

```
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeAndPlaces.weekday" ascending:YES], [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeAndPlaces.courseOrder" ascending:YES], nil]];
```

last step: fetching

```
NSError* err = nil;
list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err]];
[fetchRequest release];
```

Comment: I tend to the first version. But how to use these data? I want to draw some Buttons with 'courseName' and 'courseLocation' in the ScrollView in-code, and use their 'courseOrder' and 'weekday' to decide these Buttons' row and column. Rather than in a TableView. Can you help me?

Comment: just change the `setSortDescriptors` part to get the order. and may you give me a screenshot or a mocup the the scrollview with the buttons inside? I have an idea but first want to know if I am on the right way ;)

Comment: just like this, maybe use other control instead of button:http://a650.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/076/Purple/28/57/3f/mzl.ihjvesqc.320x480-75.jpg

Comment: looks like a case for `UICollectionViewController` :)

Comment: My effect drawing in my answer.

Comment: But I still don't know how to use these info in the result. Please tell me how to fetch them?

Comment: Let me have a try. Thank you.